# How can I fix this window error with kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

there are no mistakes on my code, when I launch my code to see the results if show me a white window. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XvdO.png)
Can you help me ?

Comment: Please share minimal code so we can find error correctly. If your codes correct, ther might be a mistake about return correct class to show widgets.

Comment: I've just fix it, it was a problem on the screenmanager !  Thx